# Re-adjusting the whole EPS file frame boundaries

Tags: ghostscript, adobe-illustrator, bounding-box, ps, eps

I have an EPS file that I want to open in Adobe Illustrator. A preview of the file rendered using the “PS View” is presented below:

[image: [[THE IMAGE]]]

The troubled file is created using Maple, and as you can see, the content is outside of the artboard! The Adobe Illustrator only takes care of what is inside the artboard, ignoring all of the outsiders that results in an empty document!
How do I re-adjust the “Bounding Box” to be able to use it in the Adobe Illustrator?

Comment: Illustrator usually has no problem with objects outside of the artboard. have you tried viewing the file in artwork mode? Some files create a mask that matches the artboard, hiding anything outside of it in Illustrator.

Comment: I'd need to see the actual EPS file before I could comment, but you could try adjusting the %%BoundingBox and %%HiResBoundingBox comments.